# eBay API: GetOrders call returning no orders

Tags: orders, ebay-api

I have placed test orders in the sandbox eBay account.

I am not able to get the orders listing from the `GetOrders` API call.

It retruns the success message but no orders are fetched.

Below are the API call details :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" ><soap:Header><RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>...</eBayAuthToken><Credentials><AppId>Clarion89-2b36-4da6-b073-00dafbcff12</AppId><DevId>f79169c1-f95b-4d23-9fe2-547504ffb827</DevId><AuthCert>...</AuthCert></Credentials></RequesterCredentials></soap:Header><soap:Body><GetOrdersRequest><DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel><Version>527</Version><CreateTimeFrom>2012-04-02T09:52:27.000Z</CreateTimeFrom><CreateTimeTo>2012-05-03T09:52:27.000Z</CreateTimeTo><OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole><OrderStatus>Active</OrderStatus><ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType></GetOrdersRequest></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Response returned as below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
   <Timestamp>2012-05-03T09:54:03.650Z</Timestamp>
   <Ack>Success</Ack>
   <Version>771</Version>
   <Build>E771_CORE_BUNDLED_14795207_R1</Build>
   <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfPages>0</TotalNumberOfPages>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>0</TotalNumberOfEntries>
   </PaginationResult>
   <HasMoreOrders>false</HasMoreOrders>
   <OrderArray/>
   <OrdersPerPage>100</OrdersPerPage>
   <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
   <ReturnedOrderCountActual>0</ReturnedOrderCountActual>
  </GetOrdersResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please tell me why i am not getting order details

Answer (score 2):

first of all i would use an higher version (i'm actually using 771 as compatibility level)

I used to have a similar problem at the very benning when i started coded for api, then i switched CreatedTime filter to NumberOfDays wich are the days to look back from today.

What language are you using to make the call?

Answer (score -1):

Check your request parameters against your orders that are stored on ebay. It may happen that there are no orders matching the parameters you are entering in your call. Try entering the most basic request parameters like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>[your authentication token]</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<CreateTimeFrom>2012-05-10T00:00:00.000Z</CreateTimeFrom>
<CreateTimeTo>2012-05-15T00:00:00.000Z</CreateTimeTo>
</GetOrdersRequest>
```

You can enter the dates as per your requirement but make sure you use the date format accepted by ebay.